# LinkedIn API v2 get user info

Tags: linkedin-api

I have person's email address and I want to find this person in LinkedIn network by this email (using their API v2) and get this person's position from the LinkedIn profile. Is it possible to do this?

Linkedin offers [Handle Lookup API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/handle-lookup) for such goals but it seems to be private. Are there any other ways to achieve that or it is possible for LinkedIn partners only? If so, what criterias do I have to meet to become LinkedIn partner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the LinkedIn support:

The permissions to access [Handle Lookup API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/handle-lookup) are no longer granted as we are not accepting partners for the program.

We currently don't offer any API's that would allow you to search by email address. Since your app would be collecting the member data, we do not offer the ability to search. If you do store member data, you need to be sure you're following the [data storage requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/data-storage-requirements). In order to view a users email address, they would first need to authenticate the app using the [authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context).